# Do vampires get tired?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, vampire-the-requiem-2e

Do vampires in Requiem 2nd edition get physically tired or exhausted from physical activities such as running, exercise or lifting weights? I can't seem to find any reference to that in any of the books, whether it's first or second edition.

Answer (score 8):

### Doesn't seem so.

The only references in the book to "exhaustion" or being "tired" come with being overtaxed on Blood or Willpower. So long as you're flush with both, you should be good.

Answer (score -7):

Vampires are known to not sleep Because theyre imortal creatures of the night. However they do get tired mentally when they dont feed. And eventually die. Many vampires sleep in coffins which in a sence recharges them, but i cant consider that actually Sleeping

Comment: I think a Vampire can't die of hunger. Becouse they sleep thousands of years without food.